# Is there a way to cast the type of a value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I am new to TypeScript.

I have some inherited code that, for some reason, uses the TypeScript [literal string type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). I have extracted an MWE ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=0&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOA3ApgJwCroM5QAUeAXIgZjGAOYCUiA3gFCKuJQCeADuoqnAHd0AG0QBeRAHIAhpMQAfKejmLJMFVLgbJISSzbA4mRIWHooyRHGDl6zNg8QB6J4hh52ACyy9pYDogC0gFQcMhwWBC8UN7s3LzWlqGIAEa8kvxCwpIA-PqO4WB4cGYAdMJw1IQAPJkiAHwQ9C6IwlS8AExkMe6IACYRHgD6YHBQQ4jA0jDC+YgAvkyLTCgYOPhEMikQkrRAA)) below:

```
function coverTest(s: string) {
    type vowel = 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u'
    for (let c of s) {
        // is there any way to coerce the type of c to be 'vowel'?
        console.log(<vowel>c) // line 2: this does _not_ fail
    }
}

coverTest('abc')
```

As documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), it seems to me (from line 2 in above code) that the custom type information is not available at run time and hence there is no way to make the code fail at run time. Is my understanding correct?

If yes, what are my options to ensure that a string (like `'abc'` passed to a call to `coverTest`) only consists of values of the custom `vowel` type? Preferably, I want to keep the definition of the type `vowel` as above, but reject the strings that contain non-vowels.

### Update (after a day)

Looking at the answers (thanks, by the way!), it appears to me that I am looking for a way to get, at run time, all the *literal* values that a custom type (using unions by `'|'`) allows (almost like an `enum`). In other words, keeping the definition of the `vowel` type above the same, is there a way to get a list of all its literal values at run time?

Comment: I think it would start with ``type VowelStr<T> = T extends Vowel ? T : T extends `${Vowel}${infer R}` ? VowelStr<R> : never;`` but I'm drawing a blank on the syntax of how to apply that constraint directly to the argument type

Comment: "As documented here, it seems to me (from line 2 in above code) that the custom type information is not available at run time and hence there is no way to make the code fail at run time. Is my understanding correct?" Yes, that is correct. Instead, you would want to make sure that it fails at compile time so `coverTest` would only take strings that contain vowels. I'm also not certain how to accomplish that though

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think that will always reduce to a single character, but if you want the literal `T` as a result, then this? `type VowelStr<T> = T extends Vowel ? T : T extends `${Vowel}${infer R}` ? R extends VowelStr<R> ? T : never : never;`

Comment: @MikeCluck, thanks! But I can't make it fail at compile time (so easily). The strings that I receive at run time are just that, strings. I want to ensure that they are made of vowels. Maybe the code needs to be restructured and I am not afraid of doing that. But if I can achieve something without a lot of changes, I'd prefer that.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Generally speaking you want to setup type guards for outside data then you can have everything all nicely typed on the inside of your application. Just a pro tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use a modified version of the conditional type [suggested by CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71372760/is-there-a-way-to-cast-the-type-of-a-value-in-typescript#comment126155833_71372760) to determine whether the string argument provided to the function matches the vowel pattern or not. If it does, the string is allowed and inferred as a literal. If it doesn't, it is rejected as not being assignable to `never`.

> I've also included an alternate assertion approach (asserting the iterable directly) to demonstrate how the compiler can infer the iterated values. This removes the need to continue to assert that `c` is `Vowel` at every usage site inside the loop.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```ts
// Derive the Vowel type from data (sorted array of vowels):

const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] as const;
type Vowel = typeof vowels[number];


// Refactor of your exmaple:

type VowelStr<T> = T extends Vowel ? T
  : T extends `${Vowel}${infer R}` ? R extends VowelStr<R> ? T
  : never : never;

function coverTest <S extends string>(s: VowelStr<S>) {
  for (const c of s as Iterable<Vowel>) {
    console.log(c);
  }
}

coverTest('iou'); // ok
coverTest('abc'); /*
          ~~~~~
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345) */


// Validation at runtime:

function assertIsVowelString <S extends string>(str: S): void {
  const sortedUniques = [...new Set(str)].sort().join('');
  if (!vowels.join('').includes(sortedUniques)) throw new Error(`"${str}" is not a vowel string`);
}

const abc = 'abc';
assertIsVowelString(abc); // will throw Error

const iou = 'iou';
assertIsVowelString(iou); // ok
```

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71372760/is-there-a-way-to-cast-the-type-of-a-value-in-typescript/71373394?noredirect=1#comment126162194_71373394): Here's an assertion function which inlines the vowel data rather than relying on an external data structure (e.g. the array in my original answer). No special types are needed for runtime validation:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcqIBQYAeADlgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIC2qA5gPwWpRYxh2ASgppMOVIiKlEAbwBQiRDGD4AhNKxDEUABZZ6iMBjqIAolgNY8bdok6dEAcgCC6bLASJgyGABsMABMnIQBueQBfeXlQSE8kGFQANXoMPwBlPgE7PF5yRDzskUQAIzg4AOQkBSUIBF4CuBwggFUwGABHEAxJAF5EAG0AOhHjU3SMKFy+IQBdIdQmqaEhgCs4ATwnEPClLEmQLCQt5Ax4EBChgQg-EECe3KXW9q6esMjo2Oh4JDEPAElkqkMllBPg8jxQcIKAA3DaBOSKFDuHB4RIpOhpTL8QTTLTMAAGACIACSyPIRInKSS0XDIRBwzF+ApQgnvKLRAD0nMQABUelBOfcWHAyJ9wN8vOxJm5xPEAEo9EB+XAAHllHgAYkgiFAMGBApI8CMhsRkFhkGwKPtkIEEH4AJ4oMAOgazbS9AB8DPhnrwSL+OG1FA1QaYSJNZotVsQAAVzZbJthUOqUVBtZ75MUnGb0E5EAAfZw+fz5mo6LBO8tKQPpsDGkZRy2od5KPYHI7OXOoJy7RBRWrIKAQXSItuIfZQQ5IJwlvy9pFRDnAJr4OpgBp5RBwVQDJzIEoQJzMJznJzuseIdcNfaoZW4frSqChhVKlV4WuAjFYqHMPKtq96gqDAhj8OB2DwWQBjyWZrTfKAInZLkeQAGXA1AxW5OQUEPCgiTnKkoiw2RlDgEA8O7Qj5CAA)

```ts
function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg ?? 'Assertion failed');
}

function isVowelString (str: string): boolean {
  const sortedUniques = [...new Set(str)].sort().join('');
  return ('aeiou').includes(sortedUniques);
}

function assertIsVowelString (str: string): void {
  assert(isVowelString(str), `"${str}" is not a vowel string`);
}
```

```ts
// Test/demo:

function getAssertionResult <AssertFn extends (...params: readonly any[]) => void>(
  assertFn: AssertFn,
  ...params: Parameters<AssertFn>
): 'pass' | 'fail' {
  try {
    assertFn(...params);
    return 'pass';
  }
  catch {
    return 'fail';
  }
}

for (const str of ['abc', 'iou']) {
  const result = getAssertionResult(assertIsVowelString, str);
  console.log({[str]: result});
}

// Logs:
// { abc: "fail" }
// { iou: "pass" }
```

Comment: This looks encouraging; I like `assertIsVowelString`. Thank you for taking time! However, this is slightly different from my MWE. I want to keep my `vowel` type the one that only accepts a certain set of known values using pipe: `type vowel = | 'a' | 'e'| 'i'| 'o'| 'u'`.  In my codebase, that type is enhanced elsewhere: `type extVowel = vowel |  'y'`

AFAIU, you have created a `Vowel` type that is sort of backed up by an array. I don't have that flexibility. Am I making it clear? Would it be possible for you to change your example to achieve that?

Comment: The `Vowel` type in my answer and the one in your question are identical. You can also use either one in a new union and the result is also identical. The difference is that the one in my answer _is_ **derived** from the array members which makes the code in the runtime assertion function both possible and establishes the relationship between the type validation and runtime validation. If runtime validation is not important, then you can remove the array and the assert function, and simply rewrite the `Vowel` type manually.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is that if I had a list like your `vowels`, there was no problem. I get a string at run time and see if it is only made of _vowel_ s. My question was to find out if that is possible without redefining my type `vowel` at all. The run time assertion _is_ what I am looking for.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade The `Vowel` type is completely unnecessary for runtime validation: [types don't exist at runtime, only at compile-time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types). See the updated information in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, @jsejcksn. I guess I am understanding this a bit more. And I admit that this is more complex (and perhaps more type-safe) than I had imagined. I am leaning more toward something like ... (see next comment).

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbiA7gUwDYRgXhgbQOQCGeANDHsiWQJaV4i0CueAugNwBQUAngA7IwA1JGiwxufEADN4w9DjAMAtgCNkAJzade-AKIAPKEJSpRRkQB8yXPB3aSGYYFCrgYoOOoAqyaAAoIAFww0GpUYADmAJQwAN7sMAkwqMiwwBjYYMiIMADKKb4IxhCR8YmSIGowvsmpMFLB0XGJzTBU0r4AhG4QAHQAFgQQvsCRjaUtLaCQIMk9qCDhvniSBFToMOVqQXgwANQN4xOJaikMamCHzQC+hzfNUxAzyHMLSwSoJuEgIAAm23sHG7sdjuLw+KBvZTAPDRGAAejhG1W602QQIUJBIA8am8fkIyAosIRMHen2+fxJBJgwPsjmcrnCKQA8plfJEgmYTE1jqdzmQiOwbg8ni9FoyoCzkGzIkA)

Comment: Another possible signature of `isVowelString` is `function isVowelString<S extends string>(str: S): str is VowelStr<S>`. That makes the type system know that `str` is a `VowelStr` after `if (isVowelStr(str))`.

Comment: @md2perpe Yep, that would effectively just be a literal string inference as long as the function returns `true` (the same as `str is S`), so it doesn't result in a transformation of any kind or new type information.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do this with generics and conditional types.

```
type Vowel = 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u';
type PickVowels<S extends string, Acc extends string = ''> = S extends `${Vowel}${infer Rest}`
    ? S extends `${infer Char}${Rest}`
        ? PickVowels<Rest, `${Acc}${Char}`>
        : never
    : Acc;

type T1 = PickVowels<'abcde'>; // 'ae'
type T2 = PickVowels<'aeiouiu'>; // 'aeiouiu'
type T3 = PickVowels<'zxcvbnmvxcmv'>; // ''

function operateOnVowelOnlyString<S extends string>(s: S extends PickVowels<S> ? S : never) {}

operateOnVowelOnlyString('abcd'); // Error
operateOnVowelOnlyString('aaa'); // Ok
operateOnVowelOnlyString('aeiou'); // Ok

// Note this only works with string literals so this would error out because its type is inferred as `string` not `aeiou`
let s = 'aeiou';
operateOnVowelOnlyString(s);
```

Comment: Hmm! That increases the _line noise_ (a term I first heard from DHH) beyond my comprehension. No? I thought I want to achieve something not so esoteric, after all.

Comment: Yeah I think it is a pretty unconventional use case for TS or most type systems for that matter. It’s a check that I’d do during runtime. But it was pretty satisfying to try to get it to work in TS for educational purposes. :)